# Maven compile does not work with provided scope

Tags: maven, scope, compilation, dependencies

I am using the below dependency in my project and I am unable to compile:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My project is a library which will be used by another project and that will supply the spring boot web and hence I am marking it as provided.

If I change the scope to compile it works fine, however I do not want to package this dependency in my jar and hence I am trying to use provided scope but it wont let me compile.

Another workaround I have found is to use `<optional>true</optional>` but on Maven's documentation, it is called as a stop gap solution.

Please advise on how to compile using provided scope.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what: "does not work" really means?

Comment: Sure. I am getting compilation errors when I use provided scope instead of default (compile) scope.

Comment: And what are the issue exactly? Please give more information otherwise no one is able to help here...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I was able to resolve this. There was another dependency that was causing some confict with provided scope. While viewing dependencies using dependency:tree this became clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maven provided scope works fine as stated in documentation. The issue occurred due to some other dependencies that were causing conflicts. As I cannot remove those, I used optional=true as a workaround.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.